# Drawing on PictureBox inside of Panel - C#

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, panel, picturebox

The question I have here is sort of a 2 parter.

I have a picturebox that is positioned inside of a panel. When I open an image, the picturebox is resized to the size of the image, while the panel stays the same size. The panel just has scrollbars to see the whole image.

There are 2 things going wrong with this.

1. When I resize the picturebox, for some reason I can only draw in the previous portion of the picturebox. Ex. The imagebox starts out by default as 200x200. I open an image that is 500x400. And I can only still draw in the 200x200 portion of the image.
2. The second issue that I am having is that when I do draw in that selective portion of the picturebox, when I scroll to where my painting is out of view, and come back, the image that i painted gone. I know there is some sort of `picturebox.invalidate()` that I need. I am just not sure how to use it.

Here is my code to get a good grasp on what I'm doing.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DrawArea = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Size.Width, pictureBox1.Size.Height );
        pictureBox1.Image = DrawArea;

        objGraphics = this.pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
            drawImage(e);
    }

    public void drawImage(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rDraw = new Rectangle();

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            rDraw.X = e.X;
            rDraw.Y = e.Y;
            rDraw.Width = 3;
            rDraw.Height = 3;
            objGraphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rDraw);
        }
    }

    private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.bmp";
            if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(open.FileName);

                pictureBox1.Size = bit.Size;
                DrawArea = bit;
                pictureBox1.Image = bit;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Failed loading image");
        }
    }
```

Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw in the picturebox's `Paint` event.

You should (almost) never draw on `CreateGraphics()`.

Comment: How exactly would I do that. I have the paint event but I am not sure how to draw exactly using the event.

Comment: Draw on `e.Graphics`.  The paint event can be fired many times (eg, if you scroll).  To force it to repaint, `Invalidate()` it.

Comment: Sorry for being so naive. I would overload the on paint event correct? passing it e from my mouse_move event?

Comment: No.  Handle the PictureBox's `Paint` event (unless you want to paint directly on the form) and use its `e`.

Comment: I am letting the user draw on the image as if it where a pencil. I don't understand how I can do this along with the mouse_over event.

Comment: Store the lines that the user drew in the mouse events, and draw all of those lines in the paint event.